# CSS 100% Height, and then Scroll DIV not page

Tags: html, css, scroll

Okay so I haven't been able to find a question with an answer yet, so I decided to make my own.

I am trying to create a 100% fluid layout, which technically I have done.
http://stickystudios.ca/sandbox/stickyplanner/layout/index2.php

BUT, what I want to do now, is to make the page 100% in HEIGHT... But I don't want the page to scroll I want the inner DIV to scroll.

So I believe in short I want it to detect the height of the viewport screen, go 100%, and then IF content is longer then the screen, scroll the specific DIV, NOT the page.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
<html>
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top: 0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

That should do it for a simple case

I believe this will work for your case

```
<html>
  <body style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="header" style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:50px;"></div>
      <div id="leftNav" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:50px; left:0; right:200px; bottom:50px;"></div>
      <div id="mainContent" style="overflow:auto; position:absolute; top:50px; left: 200px; right:0; bottom:50px;"></div>
      <div id="footer" style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; height:50px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this example will give you a static header and footer and allow the navigator and content area to be scrollable.

Comment: John, your second example worked awesome! Thank you very much, I have been hassling with this for far to long. Appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in IE8 for some reason, perhaps the JQuery CSS

Answer (score 9):

This is a different way to do this with all abs panels, it will fail on IE6, but I can provide the workaround CSS for IE6 if that is a requirement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Fluid Layout</title>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
 <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    body { background-color:black; margin:0px; padding:0px; }
    .pageBox { position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; right:20px; bottom:20px; min-width:200px}
    .headerBox { position:absolute; width:100%; height:50px; background-color:#333; }
    .contentBox { position:absolute; width:100%; top:52px; bottom:32px; background-color:blue; }
    .footerBox { position:absolute; width:100%; height:30px; background-color:#ccc; bottom:0px; }        
    .contentBoxLeft { position:absolute; width:20%; height:100%; background-color:#b6b6b6; }
    .contentBoxRight { position:absolute; width:80%; left:20%; height:100%; background-color:white; }    
    .contentBoxLeft,
    .contentBoxRight { overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>&nbsp;
    <div class="pageBox">
        <div class="headerBox">Header</div>
        <div class="contentBox">
            <div class="contentBoxLeft">ContentLeft asdf asdf adsf assf</div>
            <div class="contentBoxRight">ContentRight asdf asdfa dasf asdf asdfd asfasd fdasfasdf dasfsad fdasfds<br /><br />asdfsad ff asdf asdfasd</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footerBox">Footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: David, Awesome bud, your the first one to actually use the info I gave out, appreciate you showing the implementation. Thank you, was very useful.

Answer (score 6):

make `overflow:auto` for the div

Answer (score 2):

overflow:auto;
on the DIV style
You should just know that the size of the div should increase so it can show scrolls in it.
If you increase the page's size (which should be with style="overflow: hidden;" on the body) 
it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use position:absolute (because it messes up your print out if your margins need to be different than all zeros) then you can do it with a little bit of JavaScript.

Set up your body and div like so to allow the div to scroll:

```
<body style='overflow:hidden'>
  <div id=scrollablediv style='overflow-y:auto;height:100%'>
    Scrollable content goes here
  </div>
</body>
```

This technique depends on the div having a set height, and for that we require JavaScript.

Create a simple function to reset the height of your scrollable div

```
function calculateDivHeight(){
  $("#scrollablediv").height(window.innerHeight);
}
```

And then call this function on both page load and on resize.

```
// Gets called when the page loads
calculateDivHeight();

// Bind calculate height function to window resize
$(window).resize(function () {
  calculateDivHeight();
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that approaches the main issue, which is having `height: 100%`. However it doesn't require JS, just the height set on _all ancestors_ right to `html`. Setting `overflow` is only required on the scrolling container, not any of the ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
 <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    .modal{width:300px;border:1px solid red;overflow: auto;opacity: 0.5;z-index:2;}
    .bg{background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,red,green,yellow);width:1000px;height:2000px;top:0;left:0;}
    .btn{position:fixed;top:100px;left:100px;}
 </style>
 </head>
<body style='padding:0px;margin:0px;'>
 <div class='bg' style='position:static'></div>
 <div class='modal' style='display:none'></div>
 <button class='btn'>toggle </button>
</body>
<script>
 var str='',count=200;
 while(count--){
  str+=count+'<br>';
 }
 var modal=document.querySelector('.modal'),bg=document.querySelector('.bg'),
 btn=document.querySelector('.btn'),body=document.querySelector('body');
 modal.innerHTML=str;
 btn.onclick=function(){
  if(bg.style.position=='fixed'){
   bg.style.position='static';
   window.scrollTo(0,bg.storeTop);
  }else{
   let top=bg.storeTop=body.scrollTop;
   bg.style.position='fixed';
   bg.style.top=(0-top)+'px';
  }
  modal.style.display=modal.style.display=='none'?'block':'none';
 }
</script>
</html>
```