# Image in table cell doesn't scale down: using ie8/7

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me troubleshoot my website?

http://www.andrewstonyer.co.uk/test/

My problem:

On IE8/7 if you click on a thumbnail (only 'Pulse' and 'Time Within The Hour' are wired in right now) an overlay appears with detail of that piece.

What should happen, and does in Gecko/Webkit, is that the overlay contains a table with a heading, a scaled, centered image, and a nav menu. There is a toggle for text, which pushes up the image cell and makes the image smaller, keeping proportion. I know the overlay looks like ass right now- those are just placeholder colours :)

On IE, the image doesn't fit perfectly in the table cell, which means that everything is pushed down outside the window. I can't see the nav menu. It appears to render the image at actual pixel size (in the CSS, the img class element is set to 100% height).

The text cell is toggled with jquery, when toggled on in IE, it doesn't appear to 'squeeze' the above cell, which is what I want to happen.

Could any experts help?

Regards,
Jon

Answer (score 1):

Adding width:100% to the ov-image class in your CSS fixes this. I guess the other browsers honor display:block even for image scaling, but on IE, you have to declare the width for it to scale.

Additionally remove height:100% from the same class.

Comment: Thanks for looking David, but that didn't appear to work for me. Anyway, the failure led me to rework the overlay without the table code.

http://www.andrewstonyer.co.uk/test/

Click on the 'pulse' image to see overlay.

All the image height scaling is now done in javascript which alters css values; width by the standard css margin: auto.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working. One note, you should try to avoid javascript for setting dynamic height/width scaling. Here is an answer I gave to a previous question that shows a way to do dynamic height scaling layout using position:absolute and setting top/bottom. There are issues with IE6, but perhaps you dont need to support that browser.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731496/css-100-height-and-then-scroll-div-not-page/2731699#2731699