# CSS - element positioning using float does not work

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to position two panels and just can't get it to work...

I have a container-page wrapping two panels, each with it's own page. I want to position the panels side by side using float.

This is my CSS:

```
  .pages {width: 100%; position: absolute;}
  .leftPanel {position: relative; width: 25%; min-width:100px; float: left;}
  .rightPanel {position: static;}
```

and HTML

```
  <div class="page">
    <div id="lefty" class="leftPanel">
      <div class="page">
        <p>helloworld</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="righty" class="rightPanel">
      <div class="page">
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
      </div>
    </div>    
 </div>
```

I have to use *position:relative* for the left panel and *position:static* for the right panel.  Strangely this works in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ixowoq/2/edit) but in my actual page, the right panel with position:static always has 100% width covering the whole screen.

Any hints on what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Must you use float.  There are simpler ways to achieve what you want.  Perhaps this post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731496/css-100-height-and-then-scroll-div-not-page/2731562#2731562

Comment: if possible. I know this would be fairly easy with position:absolute

Comment: What do you mean "I have to use position:relative for the left panel and position:static for the right panel" ?

Comment: both panels act as containers for Jquery-Mobile pages. You can change these pages using CSS3 transitions. The left panel needs to be relative, otherwise you can see the transitioned-to-page being pulled up to the left of the menu and then sliding across. The right panel could be static or relative (trying now), but I cannot use pos:absolute for either one because it will break the layout of contained Jquery Mobile pages.

Comment: why do you have to use position:static? that is the element's default behavior, so normally you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div elements by default have a width of 100% of their parent.  Since you floated the lefty div you took it out of the flow so what is happening is that the lefty div is effectively sitting outside the flow of the elements. Also float causes the div to shrink-wrap to the size of it's children.  So if you are wanting to set the righty div to but up against the lefty div then you should do two things: first add `float:left; position:relative;` to the righty styling.  Second you should add a div at the bottom of that to clear your floats.

On another note you should only use a class if you are going to be styling multiple elements the same way, otherwise just style the element off of the ID.

```
  .pages {width: 100%; position: absolute;}
  .leftPanel {position: relative; width: 25%; min-width:100px; float: left;}
  .rightPanel {position: relative; float: left;}

  <div class="page">
    <div id="lefty" class="leftPanel">
      <div class="page">
        <p>helloworld</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="righty" class="rightPanel">
      <div class="page">
         <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:left;"></div>    
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating both of the panels? As of right now only the left one is floated... try floating both of them to the left and then putting the correct amount of margin between them to line them up like you want them. Or even floating one left and the other right would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS,

```
div.clear-both {clear: both;}
```

And change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="page">
  <div id="lefty" class="leftPanel">
    <div class="page"
      <p>helloworld</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="righty" class="rightPanel">
    <div class="page">
       <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
    </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```