# Scrollable Div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page with a header and footer, and a middle content div that can contain a variable amount of content that should be scrollable for the middle div only. The whole page should fill any viewport/screen size, 100% height and 100% width.

I am using this CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden}
table {height:100%;width:100%;table-layout:static;border-collapse:collapse}
.header {border-bottom:2px solid #000}
.footer {border-top:2px solid #000}
.tdcontent {height:100%}
.content {height:100%; overflow:auto;}
```

I am using this HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><td class="header"><div><?php include 'header.htm' ?></div></td></tr>
<tr><td class="tdcontent"><div class="content"><?php include 'content.htm' ?></div></td> </tr>  
<tr><td class="footer"><?php include 'footer.htm' ?></td></tr>
</table>
```

The above works fine in Chrome. If I insert more content than the screen can show, a vertical scrollbar appears for the middle content div, as expected. But in both IE and Firefox, no scroll bar appears and the content extends beyond the bottom of the page. Any ideas how to fix this problem? I have tried iframes as a cross-browser solution and it works for all of them, but for SEO reasons I do not want to use iframes.

EDIT: the problem seems to be setting height at 100%. Chrome likes it, but IE and FF seem to want fixed height in px only.

EDIT 2: I found an answer on SO at [CSS 100% Height, and then Scroll DIV not page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731496/css-100-height-and-then-scroll-div-not-page)

Comment: is this what you are looking for ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kfApH it involves padding, box-sizing and header and footer in fixed position , just like the old way of IE5.5 in quirk mode, im talking about choosing/setting the box-model

Comment: That is interesting. It produces a double scrollbar in FF, but I will play around with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
overflow:auto;// right and bottom scroll
overflow-y:auto;//only right scroll
overflow-x:auto;//only bottom scroll
```

**UPDATE:**

But this is very cool library for this task
https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.content {overflow:scroll-y}
```

My bad, I was really tired when I wrote this ^

It was `.content {overflow-y:scroll}`